# Breadboard Wiring with Seven Segment Display

Tags: raspberry-pi, cables, breadboard, wiring

So I'm planning on building a skee ball machine and as I've been looking into it I've decided to use some seven segment displays [from here](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/7-Segment-Display-3-Inches-Red-p-1192.html?cPath=34_78):

[image: 7-segments display]

As I've looked into this more I know I need a breadboard and I'm planning on using [a solderless one found here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0040Z1ERO)

[image: Breadboard]

So my plan is to use an arduino to get input from the arcade machine and then hook up a raspberry pi to get information to the bread board and light up these displays (I'll have 7 seven segment displays, so I have enough to have the word "highscore" on display at one time).

I'm fairly new to this breadboard thing and want to know what wires I would need to connect these SSD (seven segment displays) to the breadboard. I've found a couple of different wires and they're all confusing me.

Here's [the first one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0040DEI9M):

[image: Jumpers]

My fears with this one are:

1. Will they be long enough, they look rather short. 2. Are they even the right type to connect

Here's [the second one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A6SOGC4):

[image: Jumpers 2]

My fears with this one are:

1. What's the difference between the male and female ends compared to my first one?
2. Will this one work?

So I'm really confused on which ones work and would appreciate some help and guidance and hopefully gain some knowledge of this.

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to solder wire to the pins?

Comment: Ooh you're right @Dave Tweed

Comment: Also i want to be able to rearrange pins later and also possibly use the board for other things without paying $50 to get a new set of displays and a new breadboard

Comment: You solder the wires to the segments, not the breadboard.

Comment: OK, but i still would rather not, if it is absolutely necessary i will, but I'd prefer not

Comment: Breadboards are not intended for permanent work and will not work properly in a final product. Even in prototypes, you'll get wires disconnecting, brushing up against VCC or GND, risking burning up your componentes. It will be useful to have a proof of concept built in a protoboard, but you can use fewer displays with shorter cables. Jumpers like the ones you showed are definitely long enough for your skee ball machine.

Comment: @Ricardo then what do you suggest i do?

Comment: In summary, after you're past the breadboard proof-of-concept phase, look for sturdier construction methods.

Comment: @Ricardo thank you! I'll look more into it after, but what are your suggestions for at least the breadboard part as i at least want to see if it will work as i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wires you show are meant for both ends to be connected to the breadboard.  They have nice and sturdy pins on the ends that are just right for the sockets in the breadboard.

However, if you want to connect points on the breadboard to something off the breadboard, like your 7-segment LEDs apparently, then these aren't appropriate.  Fortunately single strand #22 wire works just fine in these breadboards too.  Get a roll of it, cut each wire to the length you need, solder one end to the LEDs, then stick the other end into whatever socket in the breadboard you want.